# Python: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python-2.7, type-conversion, python-requests

I get a Typecast - Error, when I try to convert unicode-strings, parsed from a website.
Here are the relevant codebits:

```
# special IPython command to prepare the notebook for matplotlib

%matplotlib inline 

from fnmatch import fnmatch

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests
from pattern import web

# set some nicer defaults for matplotlib
from matplotlib import rcParams

#these colors come from colorbrewer2.org. Each is an RGB triplet
dark2_colors = [(0.10588235294117647, 0.6196078431372549, 0.4666666666666667),
                (0.8509803921568627, 0.37254901960784315, 0.00784313725490196),
                (0.4588235294117647, 0.4392156862745098, 0.7019607843137254),
                (0.9058823529411765, 0.1607843137254902, 0.5411764705882353),
                (0.4, 0.6509803921568628, 0.11764705882352941),
                (0.9019607843137255, 0.6705882352941176, 0.00784313725490196),
                (0.6509803921568628, 0.4627450980392157, 0.11372549019607843),
                (0.4, 0.4, 0.4)]

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 6)
rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150
rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = dark2_colors
rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2
rcParams['axes.grid'] = True
rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = '#eeeeee'
rcParams['font.size'] = 14
rcParams['patch.edgecolor'] = 'none'

def get_poll_xml(id):
    poll = requests.get("http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/"+str(id)+".xml").text
    return poll

import re

def _strip(s):

    return re.sub(r'[\W_]+', '', s)

def plot_colors(xml):

    dom = web.Element(xml)
    result = {}
    for graph in dom.by_tag('graph'):
        title = _strip(graph.attributes['title'])
        result[title] = graph.attributes['color']
    return result

def rcp_poll_data(xml):
    dates = []
    graph1 = []
    graph2 = []
    data = web.Element(xml)
    for item in data.by_tag('series')[0].by_tag('value'):
        dates.append(item.content)
    for item in data.by_tag('graph')[0].by_tag('value'):
        graph1.append(float(unicode(item.content)))
    for item in data.by_tag('graph')[1].by_tag('value'):
        graph2.append(float(unicode(item.content)))
    return pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.to_datetime(dates), data.by_tag('graph')[0].title: graph1, data.by_tag('graph')[1].title: graph2})
```

When I execute this codepart:

```
print rcp_poll_data(get_poll_xml(1044))
```

Then I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-76ebd15c4a1d> in <module>()
----> 1 print rcp_poll_data(get_poll_xml(1044))

<ipython-input-7-02e6590229d7> in rcp_poll_data(xml)
     53         dates.append(item.content)
     54     for item in data.by_tag('graph')[0].by_tag('value'):
---> 55         graph1.append(float(unicode(item.content)))
     56     for item in data.by_tag('graph')[1].by_tag('value'):
     57         graph2.append(float(unicode(item.content)))

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I already tried converting directly to `float(item.count)` or via string `float(string(item.count))`, but I always get a type error...

If someone can help or can send me to a topic, where I can find a aolution I would be glad. I don't know where to look for the error.

Thx

Comment: Can you try printing the value of `item.content` and `unicode(item.content)` before line 55?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked [the xml file](http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/1044.xml) you retrieve in your code  and found that the `value` elements starting with `xid="1824"` have no content so you get an empty string that throws your error when you try to convert it to a float. The solution is to check that the content of `item.content` is not empty before converting to float.

```
for item in data.by_tag('graph')[0].by_tag('value'):
    if item.content:
        graph1.append(float(unicode(item.content)))
```

In the for loop following the one above you have to make the same correction.